# Is there a way to send distance values of a DW3000 and a iOS device?

Tags: esp32, uwb

Is there a feasible solution for sending distance values between a DW3000 device and an iOS device? I have searched extensively online to find an implementation of this idea, but haven't been successful. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in finding the appropriate resources or code implementation to achieve this.